# Optional type error in Swift: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the photo albums from facebook using FBSDK v4.x. I use this code below and I get the result as json after I print it out, but afterwards it cause an error like this: '*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*' on code in this line: *let graphData = result.valueForKey("data") as! [FBSDKShareAPI]* .so can anyone please help me to solve this error. Thanks in advance.

```
func fetchAlbum(){
    print(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
    let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me?fields=albums", parameters: nil);
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if let gotError = error{
            print(gotError.description);
        }
        else{
            print("fetched data: \(result)")
            if result != nil{ 
            let graphData = result.valueForKey("data") as! [FBSDKShareAPI]  
            var albums:[AlbumModel] =  [AlbumModel]();
            for obj:FBSDKShareAPI in graphData{
                let desc = obj.description;
                println(desc);
                let name = obj.valueForKey("name") as! String;
                println(name);
                if(name == "ETC"){
                    let test="";
                }
                let id = obj.valueForKey("id") as! String;
                var cover = "";
                if let existsCoverPhoto : AnyObject = obj.valueForKey("cover_photo"){
                    let coverLink = existsCoverPhoto as! String;
                    cover = "/\(coverLink)/photos";
                }
                //println(coverLink);
                let link = "/\(id)/photos";
                let model = AlbumModel(name: name, link: link, cover:cover);
                albums.append(model);
                }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("albumNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["data":albums]);

            }
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: try use `as?` maybe, it looks like you are trying to cast a value that is nil

Comment: result might not be nil, but result.valueForKey("data") can be nil and you're getting the error by unwrapping it, i.e. as! (with an exclamation point)

Comment: That is good to us as?, but it wil be cause some problem with this line:  ' for obj:FBSDKShareAPI in graphData{   ' like this: '[FBSDKShareAPI]?' does not have member named 'Generator'.

Answer (score 0):

better yet, you could go

```
if let graphData = result?.valueForKey("data") as? [FBSDKShareAPI] {
    //bla
}
```

and it should do all the nil checking for you

Comment: It's probably bad form to use `valueForKey()`. I think it's better to firm up what type of object `result` is so you can safely use `result["data"]` instead.

Comment: I try it and it does not execute the block of code in side the curly brace at all. Any idea?

Comment: @aaron, i actually agree, was just regurgitating the code.
@sarayakchak it means either result is nil, or it cant cast the valueForKey("data") to a `FBSDKShareAPI` type. I advise that you put a breakpoint and see what the result object looks like on the inside

Comment: @sarayakchak is it because result["data"] is `nil`? Put a breakpoint above that `if` clause and check for the content of `result` dict.

Comment: So what should I use instead of using FBSDKShareAPI? In FBSDK v 3.x I use FBGraphObject, but in FBSDK v4.x I don't have any idea. Anything to replace it?

Comment: It like this: (lldb) po result?["data"]
Optional(nil) . So what should I need to do next?

Comment: im not familiar with the FBSDK but you will need to find out why the result object (or result["data"]) is not being populated, maybe look at the error object and see if it has any errors that could lead you in the right direction

Comment: I cannot find any problem beside this, and I also cannot fix it.

Comment: I try around it many times , yet I still cannot solve the problem. Any idea?

Comment: i think you will have to ask a separate question for that, i dont have any experience with FBSDK so i dont know.

Comment: Thanks @Fonix , is there anyone have experience with FBSDK?

Answer (score 0):

Like this works fine:

```
    func fetchAlbum(){
    print(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
    let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/albums", parameters: nil);
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if let gotError = error{
            print(gotError.description);
        }
        else{
            let graphData: NSArray! = (result?["data"])! as? NSArray
            if (graphData != nil){

                var albums:[AlbumModel] =  [AlbumModel]();
                var obj: NSArray?
                for obj in graphData{
                let desc = obj.description;
                let name = obj.valueForKey("name") as! String;
                if(name == "ETC"){
                    let test="";
                }
                let id = obj.valueForKey("id") as! String;
                var cover = "";
                if let existsCoverPhoto : AnyObject = obj.valueForKey("cover_photo"){
                    let coverLink = existsCoverPhoto as! String;
                    cover = "/\(coverLink)/photos";
                }
                let link = "/\(id)/photos";
                let model = AlbumModel(name: name, link: link, cover:cover);
                albums.append(model);
                }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("albumNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["data":albums]);

                }else{
                    print("--------------------------")
            }

        }

    })
}
```